# Problem with start date and scheduled date in Apache Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am working with [Apache Airflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Airflow) and I have a problem with the scheduled day and the starting day.

I want a [DAG](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html) to run every day at 8:00 AM UTC. So, I did:

```py
default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': datetime(2020, 12, 7, 10, 0,0),
        'email': ['example@emaiil.com'],
        'email_on_failure': True,
        'email_on_retry': False,
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(hours=5)
    }
# Never run
dag = DAG(dag_id='id', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='0 8 * * *',catchup=True)
```

The day I upload the DAG was 2020-12-07 and I wanted to run it on 2020-12-08 at 08:00:00.

I set the start_date at 2020-12-07 at 10:00:00 to avoid running it at 2020-12-07 at 08:00:00 and only trigger it the next day, but it didn't work.

Then I modified the starting day:

```py
default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': datetime(2020, 12, 7, 7, 59,0),
        'email': ['example@emaiil.com'],
        'email_on_failure': True,
        'email_on_retry': False,
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(hours=5)
    }
# Never run
dag = DAG(dag_id='etl-ca-cpke-spark_dev_databricks', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='0 8 * * *',catchup=True)
```

Now the start date is 1 minute before the DAG should run, and indeed, because the catchup is set to True, the DAG has been triggered for 2020-12-07 at 08:00:00, but it has not being triggered for 2020-12-08 at 08:00:00.

Why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Airflow schedules tasks at the *end* of the interval ([See documentation reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.13/scheduler.html))

Meaning that when you do:

```
start_date: datetime(2020, 12, 7, 8, 0,0)
schedule_interval: '0 8 * * *'
```

The **first** run will kick in at `2020-12-08` at `08:00`+- (depends on resources)

This run's `execution_date` will be: `2020-12-07 08:00`

The **next** run will kick in at `2020-12-09` at `08:00`

This run's `execution_date` of `2020-12-08 08:00`.

Since today is `2020-12-08` the next run didn't kick in because it's not the *end* of the interval yet.

Comment: Then if I want to start running `2020-12-08` at `08:00` and after that run every day at `08:00` I should set the start date at start_date: `2020-12-06 08:00`?

I don't understand why if start date is `2020-12-07 08:00`, it doesn't run on 2020-12-07 08:00 and 2020-12-08 08:00.

Comment: You are interpreting `start_date` like cronjob where you specify when and it's starting on that date. This is not how Airflow works. Airflow takes the start_date + interval when this period **END** it start the run. The logic behind this is when you write ETL you want to run at the end of interval over the window -> today you want to process yesterday data.

Comment: Then if I want to modify my dag to start being scheduled every day at 08:00:00 from tomorrow on, what start date I should set?

Comment: Go with the same logic. The run kicks in at the end of interval so `start_date = datetime(2020, 12, 8, 8, 0,0)` and interval of `0 8 * * *` will end at `2020-12-09 08:00` and that is when the first run will kick in. Note that this run will have execution_date of `2020-12-08 08:00`