# Schedule interval in airflow

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am trying to figure out how the dag interval works.

```
* * * * *
M H D M Y
```

And time is in UTC.

Exmaple:

```
29 21 * * *
```

It would mean to run every day at 21:29.

I have seen an example where the year was 4. What would this mean?

```
29 21 * * 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`29 21 * * 4` means at 21:29 on Thursday. See [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#29_21_*_*_4)

So following times are:

```
at 2020-12-17 21:29:00
then at 2020-12-24 21:29:00
then at 2020-12-31 21:29:00
then at 2021-01-07 21:29:00
then at 2021-01-14 21:29:00
```

However Airflow is not crontab. The running of task is based on `start_date` and `interval`. See the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65196414/problem-with-start-date-and-scheduled-date-in-apache-airflow/65196624#65196624)