# Airflow schedule_interval and start_date to get it to always fire the next interval

Tags: cron, airflow, mwaa

How can I configure airflow (mwaa) so that it will fire at the same time (6am PST) every day regards of when the dag is deployed?

I have tried what makes sense to me:

1. set the schedule_interval to `0 6 * * *`.
2. set the start date to:

```
now = datetime.utcnow()
now = now.replace(tzinfo=pendulum.timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))
previous_five_am = now.replace(hour = 5, minute = 0, second = 0, microsecond = 0)
start_date = previous_five_am
```

It seems that whenever I deploy by setting the start_date to 5am the previous day it would always fire at the next 6am no matter what time I deploy the dag or do a airflow update

Comment: I had a similar problem check the answer on my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67212884/how-to-make-a-dag-in-apache-airflow-run-like-a-simple-cron-job/67218114?noredirect=1#comment118816954_67218114

Comment: To be honest haven't found a good solution

Answer (score 5):

Your confusion may be because you expect Airflow to schedule DAGs like cronjob when it's not.
The first DAG Run is created based on the minimum `start_date` for the tasks in your DAG. Subsequent DAG Runs are created by the scheduler process, based on your DAG’s `schedule_interval`, sequentially. Airflow schedule tasks at the **END** of the interval (See [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/scheduler.html)) you can view this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65196624/14624409) for examples.

As for your sample code - never set your `start_date` to be dynamic. It's a bad practice that can sometimes lead to DAG never being executed because `now()` always moves to `now() + interval` may never be reached see Airflow [FAQ](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date).

Comment: In my case start date is 5am yesterday so that plus one interval (24 hours) would make the next execution date = tmrw at 6am, why is that not the case? Also if I set a static start date, it ends up being far in the past and then airflow will create tasks and execution dates for all the intervals between, and this results in many failures (noise). Even if I set catchup=False, in order to prevent backfill too many intervals are created. How can I configure these two values so that I can ensure that only the next days interval is scheduled?