# Why Are My Airflow Jobs Running “One Interval Late”?

Tags: airflow

For example, I created a new DAG at 11:30. The DAG is supposed to run on the first minute of every hour (Cron: 0 * * * *). I expected the DAG to start at 12:00. However the DAG first started at 13:00. The Second started at 14:00 while `Next run` in UI is 13:00

I know that, it's mentioned in [docs](https://%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/scheduler.html)

`**Let’s Repeat That**, the scheduler runs your job one schedule AFTER the start date, at the END of the interval.`

But I don't know What's the use of doing that? Why don't run at the start of the day like cron job?
Does anyone have any documentation explaining this issue?
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Airflow Execution Date is Confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67251814/airflow-execution-date-is-confusing)