# How do I stop Apache Airflow running a task the first time when I unpause it?

Tags: cron, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I have a [DAG](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html). Here is a sample of the parameters.

```
dag = DAG(
    'My Dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Cron Job : My Dag',
    schedule_interval='45 07 * * *',
    # start_date=days_ago(0),
    start_date = datetime(2021, 4, 6, 10, 45),
    tags=['My Dag Tag'],
    concurrency = 1,
    is_paused_upon_creation=True,
    catchup=False # Don’t run previous and backfill; run only latest
)
```

Reading the documentation from Apache Airflow, I think I have set the DAG to run at 7:45 every day. However, if I pause the DAG and unpause it a couple of days later, it still runs as soon as I unpause it (of course, for that day) as catch=False which avoids backfills.

That is not the expected behaviour, right?

I mean, I scheduled it on 7:45. When I unpause it at 10:00, it should not be running at all until the next 7:45.

What am I missing here?

Comment: This is expected. It's a bit difficult to explain it with the example you shown because your example isn't real. You provided a start_date of yesterday and you claim the dag has been paused of a few days. This doesn't make sense. Please add a real dag example with information about what runs were executed and the run that you have issue with and I will be able to explain it to you with your own example.

Comment: This example is very much real. The start date provided is 6th of April 2021 which is not yesterday but 13 days behind. I have only changed the name of the DAG because of the confidentiality of information.
Since this is a real example, please explain it if you can.

Comment: ho sorry misread. Please add the execution_dates of the runs that were created and when exactly you paused and unpaused

Comment: The last time it ran on was 7th of April, 2021. And since then i had paused it. When i unpaused it today (it ran once) as soon as i unpaused. Is this behaviour expected? Because for setting up a cron like dag we would generally want it to run on the next schedule after unpausing.

Comment: @raaj - did you come up with a workaround? I have the exact same problem. I don't want anything to run "right now". I want crontime behavior

Comment: @user3240688 Not yet mate, i unpause it at the time i want it running, so it seems like the first run is in the correct expected time.

Comment: @raaj - what do you mean "unpause it at the time i want it running"? Like you have a job at 7:45 everyday, and you paused it. When it's time to unpause, you wait until 7:45 the next day to unpause?

Comment: @user3240688  If you want to schedule your job at 7:45 everyday why would you pause it? If you pause it for a few days and want to unpause it, have the backfill parameter set to False so that it does not run the previous scheduled runs.
I am handling the problem of first time running by keeping the jobs paused on creation by default and unpausing the job (expecting it to run once) and then leaving it on schedule.

Comment: @raaj, same situation I am going through i.e. Airflow always kicks in a DAG run immediately so I see two runs happening subsequently (one is manual and second is scheduled). So yes I want exactly the same behaviour that Airflow should always consider the next scheduled day for run.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you are familiar with the scheduling mechanism of Airflow. If this is not the case please read *[Problem with start date and scheduled date in Apache Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65196414/problem-with-start-date-and-scheduled-date-in-apache-airflow/65196624#65196624)* before reading the rest of the answer.

As for your case:

You had one/several runs as expected when you deployed the DAG. At some point you paused the DAG on `2021-04-07`, today (`2021-04-19`) you unpaused it. Airflow then executed a DAG run with `execution_date='2021-04-18'`.

**This is expected.**

The reason for this is based on the scheduling mechanism of Airflow.

Your last run was on `2021-04-07` and the interval is `45 07 * * *` (every day at 07:45). Since you paused the DAG, the runs of `2021-04-08, 2021-04-09, ... , 2021-04-17` were never created. When you unpaused the DAG, Airflow didn't create these runs because of `catchup=False`, however, today's run (`2021-04-19`) isn't part of the catchup. It was scheduled because the interval `of execution_date=2021-04-18` has reached its end cycle, and thus started running.

The behavior that you are experiencing isn't different than deploying this fresh DAG:

```
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 1, 1),

}
with DAG(dag_id='stackoverflow_question',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval='45 07 * * *',
         catchup=False
         ) as dag:
    DummyOperator(task_id='some_task')
```

As soon as you will deploy it, a single run will be created:

[image]

[image]

The DAG's `start_date` is `2020-01-01` with `catchup=False`. I deployed the DAG today (`19/Apr/2021`), so it created a run with execution_date='2021-04-18' that started to run today, `2021-04-19`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Really appreciate it. However I am in a situation where I would rather have my DAGs run at around the same schedule everyday or not at all. This behaviour is somehow counter intuitive to that. Ideally one would expect something to run at the given schedule time. Is there a way to achieve this behaviour in Airflow? That is skipping this instance of run when unpausing a DAG and running the next one onwards.

Comment: @raaj if you want your unpaused DAG to start with the run for April 19 then unpause it on April 20.

Comment: @raaj This was explanation of Airflow behavior. You are now asking how to workaround it . Again this is a matter of understanding the scheduling mechanism. If you want to parse data of 2021-04-18 then unpause the dag at 2021-04-19.

Comment: So essentially to maintain the ETL logic it is set up to have a behaviour of not following the specified cron which again is a very major deciding characteristic of Airflow. For example if i would want to have a pipeline to do a process at a specified time in a day or rather not do it at all (at any other time), Airflow it seems is not an adequate tool judging by its behaviour. Because it will run the previous backlog of atleast one instance immediately for which i have no control.

Comment: @raaj This is how the Airflow works. It is going to change in the future AIP-39 Richer scheduler_interval is already accepted and in progress. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-39+Richer+scheduler_interval

Comment: @raaj if issue is solved consider accepting the answer