# Airflow start Dag on yesterday

Tags: airflow

When I deploy a new dag on airflow, let's say I deploy it today (28 April).
And I have the Cron expression as this: `0 3 * * *`, then I expect the first run is on `29 April at 3 am. however, I get a run as soon as deploy with this run id:` 2021-04-27, 03:00:00`.

Dag code:

```
DAG(
    dag_id="namexx",
    schedule_interval='0 3 * * *',
    max_active_runs=1,
    is_paused_upon_creation=False,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=1),
    catchup=False,
    default_args={
        "start_date": datetime(2021, 1, 1),
        "retries": 0,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=1)
    }
```

)

Any idea why is that?

Comment: Please post the DAG code

Comment: i added dag code in the question

Comment: if solved your question consider accepting answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i stop airflow running a task the first time when i unpause it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67160748/how-do-i-stop-airflow-running-a-task-the-first-time-when-i-unpause-it)

Answer (score 0):

This is expected.
Airflow schedule DAGs at the end of the interval.
if `start_date` is `2021-01-01` and interval is hourly a run will be triggered as soon as the DAG deployed.

See also previous [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67161656/14624409), [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65196624/14624409) on this subject