# Airflow dag is not running as per start date and schedule interval

Tags: airflow-scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

Today is 6th may.

The dag arguments are:

```
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 6),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
```

The schedule interval is:

```
schedule_interval="0 14 * * *"
```

It should have started at 2021-05-06 at 14 UTC.

[image]

But it has not been started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected.

`start_date` of `2021-05-06` and interval of `0 14 * * *` means that the first run will start on `2021-05-07 14:00` this run will have `execution_date` of `2021-05-06 14:00`

To understand why please read [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65196624/14624409) on this subject

Comment: So if today is  6th may and I want to run it at 2021-05-06 14:00, I would need to give start date as  2021-05-05 14:00? @Elad

Comment: You don't need to change the start date every time. Airflow continue to trigger tasks according to the schedule unless you specify `end_date`

Comment: That I understand so if today is 10 and I want the dag to run on 2021-05-10 14:00, the I would need to give start date of 2021-05-09 and interval 14:00? @Elad