# Airflow: how can i automate such that a query runs for every date specified rather than hard coding?

Tags: hive, airflow

I am new to airflow so apoliges if this has been asked somewhere.

I have a query i run in hive that is partitioned on year month so e.g. 202001.

how can i run a query which specifies a variable for different values within the query  in airflow? eg. taking this example

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.mysql_operator import MySqlOperator

default_arg = {'owner': 'airflow', 'start_date': '2020-02-28'}

dag = DAG('simple-mysql-dag',
          default_args=default_arg,
          schedule_interval='00 11 2 * *')

mysql_task = MySqlOperator(dag=dag,
                           mysql_conn_id='mysql_default', 
                           task_id='mysql_task'
                           sql='<path>/sample_sql.sql',
                       params={'test_user_id': -99})
```

where my sample_sql.hql looks like:

```
ALTER TABLE sample_df DROP IF EXISTS
PARTITION (
    cpd_ym = ${ym}
) PURGE;

INSERT INTO sample_df
PARTITION (
    cpd_ym = ${ym}
)
SELECT
  * 

from sourcedf 

; 

ANALYZE TABLE sample_df
PARTITION (
    cpd_ym = ${ym}
)
COMPUTE STATISTICS;

ANALYZE TABLE sample_df
PARTITION (
    cpd_ym = ${ym}
)
COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS;
```

i want to run the above for different values of ym using airflow e.g. between 202001 and 202110 how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused because you are asking about Hive yet you show example of `MySqlOperator`. In any case assuming the the sql/hql parameter is templated you can use `execution_date` directly in your query. Thus you can extract the year & month to be used for the partition value.

Example:

```
mysql_task = MySqlOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='mysql_task',
    sql="""SELECT {{ execution_date.strftime('%y%m') }}""",
)
```

[image]

So in your `sample_sql.hql` it will be:

```
ALTER TABLE sample_df DROP IF EXISTS
PARTITION (
    cpd_ym = {{ execution_date.strftime('%y%m') }}
) PURGE;
```

You mentioned that you are new to Airflow so make sure you are aware what `execution_date` is and how it's being calculated (if you are not check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65196624/14624409)). You can do string manipulations to other [macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html) as well. Choose the macro that is suitable to your needs (`execution_date` / `prev_execution_date` / `next_execution_date` / etc...).

Comment: so would i need to do somehing like : 

for date in range(20201,202105) : 
mysql_task = MySqlOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='mysql_task',
    sql="""SELECT {{ date }}""",
) ??

Comment: Why? if you create a daily runs then each run process a single day. If you want to run for 2 days no need for a loop - just execute two dagruns.