# How to fix AIRFLOW one day LAG ISSUE

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG with start date as 2021-09-16 , and schedule interval as '0 8 * * *'.
So on 17th date , i see airflow schedule runs for 16th date.

Can anyone help me how to overcome this,
I want to execute 17th date data on 17th date.

Answer (score 0):

This is how Airflow works.
DAGs are scheduled at the END of the interval. You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65196624/14624409) for more information about it.

That said for Airflow 2.2.0 release which is now in [beta testing](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/2.2.0b1/) includes [AIP-39 Richer scheduler_interval](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-39+Richer+scheduler_interval) which decouples the "when to run" from the "what data window to process". So in the near future what you are asking for will be possible.