# Airflow Scheduler Catchup

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, airflow, scheduled-tasks

if first time: then runs include from start date was my understanding

so 10 am then 10:10 then 10:20 are the 3 times before 10:30. Not sure why the answer is 2.

[Why not 3?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rhmJ.png)

Comment: please show your code, so we can have a context for your question.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/65196624/14624409