# schedule airflow 2 times in a day

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am new to Airflow and wanted to ask how to schedule a airflow workflow 2 times in a day e.g. I need to schedule a airflow dag at 10:00 am and 7:00 pm  from 2022-03-24, so after some research I think it will be like

```
interval='0 10,19 * * *'
date='2022-03-23'
schedule_interval=interval
start_date=date
```

is my understanding is correct ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You will need to create `DAG` object as:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
dag = DAG(dag_id='my_dag',
          schedule_interval='0 10,19 * * *',
          start_date=datetime(2022, 3, 23),
          catchup=False)
```

Note: if you want your first run to start on `2022-03-24` at `10:00`  then your `start_date` needs to be `datetime(2022, 3, 23, 19, 0)` this is because Airflow schedule runs at the end of the interval. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65196624/14624409) for more information about it.

Comment: Thanks @Elad , it make sense and worked , I marked as Answer ,

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your understanding is correct. Instead of using extra variables you can feed direct values while creating `DAG` object.

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
with models.DAG(
      dag_id='my_dag',
      schedule_interval='0 10,19 * * *',
      start_date=datetime(2022, 3, 23),
      catchup=False
) as dag:
```

You can also provide default_args,retries,concurrencies, etc depends on your dag behaviour.