# How to pass Yesterday's date as parameter to Airflow Task

Tags: airflow

I need to pass yesterday's date as parameter to my airflow task. I tried using the following.

`{{ prev_execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}`. This block is taking today's date when I manually trigger the DAG. Can someone help here.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected.

When manually triggering DAG, the schedule will be ignored, and `prev_ds == next_ds == ds`

You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#why-next-ds-or-prev-ds-might-not-contain-expected-values)

However for scheduled runs the `execution_date` is always 1 cycle behind (see [Problem with start date and scheduled date in Apache Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65196414/problem-with-start-date-and-scheduled-date-in-apache-airflow) for more information about it.

You will need to look in the [macros page](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html#templates-reference) to find the right macro for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Use `yesterday_ds` variable from the task instance template context which is [computed based on the execution_date](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1998) of the DagRun.

Comment: Will this work even if it is a manual or scheduled run?