# Airflow scheduled dags now working as expected

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I cannot understand how scheduler works, I created some dags with:

```
schedule_interval="0 21 * * *",
start_date=pendulum.datetime(2022, 5, 3, tz="UTC"),
catchup=False,
"max_active_runs": 1,
```

I activated the dag yesterday afternoon around 15.00 and I executed manually the dags to verify they works.

This morning I checked the dag execution and I saw the the dags have not been executed yesterday (2022-05-03 at 21.00) as expected (this is the next run date reported by airflow) why?

What am I wronging?

I am using airflow 2.2.4
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual runs start as soon as you trigger it.
Scheduled runs are subject to Airflow scheduling mechanisem. I explained it in [Problem with start date and scheduled date in Apache Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65196414/problem-with-start-date-and-scheduled-date-in-apache-airflow)

In your case start date of `2022-05-03` with interval of `0 21 * * *` means that the first run will start on `2022-05-04 21:00`. The `execution_date` of this run will be `2022-05-03 21:00`.
So if you wanted the first run to start on `2022-05-03 21:00` you need to set:

```
start_date=pendulum.datetime(2022, 5, 2, tz="UTC"),
schedule_interval="0 21 * * *",
```

Alternatively, if you want to specify exact run times you will need to use [Timetables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/timetable.html) then you can [customize DAG Scheduling with Timetables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/timetable.html).

Comment: Ok, so today is the 2022-05-04, I want that the today ad 21.00 the dags shall be executed with the current date I should set: start_date=pendulum.datetime(2022, 5, 4, tz="UTC")? Is it correct?

Comment: You are confusing between when the DAG is executed with what data interval you process. I don't know what your DAG is doing but you can get any date reference you need for the actual DAG work if you will use macros https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html

Comment: Yes, I have a lot of confusion and reading the documentation I cannot understand until now, I want to schedule a dag as crontab with logical date that is equal to the time when the dag is triggered by the scheduler, this is my objective.

Comment: But Airflow is not crontab... The scheduling logic is as I explained. You can not change it.