# "execution_date" is passing previous day's date in airflow dag (catch up mode is false)

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x

My airflow dag has catchup as false

Now when I am trying to pass execution_date airflow variable to a script then it it passing the date for previous day.

My airflow timezone is set as America/Los_angelos in the airflow.cfg file (PST TIMEZONE)

Also, it is defintely not a timezone issue. I checked the timings in UTC. The PST dag time is on same UTC day

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/65196624/14624409

Comment: @EladKalif it is not thaf issue. I have already checked it

Comment: It sound like it is? execution_date is always 1 interval behind. So if you have daily job it will be 1 day behind. This is exactly what is explained in the answer I liked. If you feel differently please edit your question and clarify.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass the current date (i.e the date the DAG is triggered) you need to pass `data_interval_end`. This date represents the end of the data interval that the DAG covers and will be the date that the DAG is triggered.

`data_interval_end` is a property on the `dag_run` [object](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dagrun/index.html#airflow.models.dagrun.DagRun)

The reason why `execution_date` is one interval behind is explained here:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#faq-what-does-execution-date-mean

The `data_interval` is only available in Airflow 2.2+. If you are on a lower version, you will have to work it out yourself using the schedule and the execution date.